# How to send REST request to a pod with C# Kubernetes API

Tags: c#, kubernetes

I'm currently writing my first program using the C# Kubernetes API. I want to send REST requests to a service that is running within a pod in my cluster. Does the library have any functionality to do that? I already tried to get the IP of the pod and then send the request manually, but I can't find a way to get this information.

Comment: You don't need the Kubernetes API for this.  The Service in front of your target pod [has a DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services); configure your client with that name as a host name and make an ordinary HTTP call.  (Both need to be running inside the cluster.)

Comment: The previous comment should be an answer instead :)

Comment: @DavidMaze Alright, then my question would be how to find out the DNS of the service. The program needs to find that by itself, I can't hardcode it or look it up and enter it manually.

Comment: How would you find it?  Is there something you already know about the service you're trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it now, thanks to the Input of David Maze. I will accept this answer as soon as I've gotten around to test it.

@DavidMaze Feel free to post this answer yourself, then I will accept that one instead.

```
config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile();
client = new Kubernetes(config);

V1ServiceList services = client.ListNamespacedService("MyNamespace");

foreach(var s in services.Items)
{
  if (s.Metadata.Name.Contains("MyService"))
  {
    standardHTTPRequest(s.Spec.ClusterIP);
  }
}
```